# Easy way to find the eigenvalues of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have a $n \times n$ matrix A that we can write as

> $A = I + x(B - I) = (1-x)I + xB$,

where $I$ is the identity matrix and $B$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with $b_{ij} =1$ for $0 \leq i,j \leq n$. Furthermore $x \in [-1,1]$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are given by $(1-x)$ with multiplicity n-1 and $(1-x) +nx$ with multiplicity 1.

I checked this for $n=3$, by writing the determinant out.

My question is, is there a more convenient way to see that the eigenvalues are indeed given by $(1-x)$ with multiplicity n-1 and $(1-x) +nx$ with multiplicity 1 for general $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see by definition that the eigenvectors of $A$ are those of $B$ (excluding the trivial case $x=0$)
$$
Av=(1-x)v+xBv=\lambda v.
$$
Eigenvalues of $B$ are zeros (multiplicity $n-1$) and $n$, then setting $Bv=0$ we get $\lambda=1-x$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and by $Bv=nv$ we get $\lambda=1-x+xn$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Your Matrix $B$ has a one dimensional row space as every row is identical. It is easy to check that any constant vector $c$ has the property that $Bc=nc$, and is therefore an eigenvector for $B$ that is not in the $n-1$ dimensional kernel for $B$. Now, for $(1-x)I$ every vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1-x$. Therefore, anything in the $n-1$ dimensional kernel of $B$ will be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1-x$ and any constant vector will have eigenvalue $(1-x)+nx$.